# Codeigniter cannot update the value for one row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to change the value of 'city' in the row where the value of 'email' equals to $user_email. The problem is that it changes the value of 'city' in all the rows of the table 'users'. Please help me to find the mistake:

Here is my model:

```
public function did_change_city($user_email){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('email' => $user_email));

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

    if ($this->db->update('users',array('city' => $this->input->post('city'))))

        {return true;}

        else

        {return false;}
    } else {return false;}

                }
```

Comment: is email your primary key?

Comment: `$this->db->update('users',array('city' => $this->input->post('city')), array('email' => $user_email));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add where condition before updating the record

```
$this->db->where('email' , $user_email);
$result = $this->db->update('users',array('city' => $this->input->post('city')));
```

and use the $result variable in your if condition

or you can use

```
$this->db->update('mytable', array('city' => $this->input->post('city')), "`email` = $user_email");
```

OR you can use the syntax given in your comments (2nd one).. all the best